# How to advance a for loop by 2 iterations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, file-io

I'm reading a large text file and I need to read a number from a specific line. The file looks like this:

```
....
unknown number of lines
....
ABCD
some random stuff
a number I want to read
....
....
```

I want to read the number from the line that is 2 lines after a "signature" line that's `ABCD`, which is unique. Right now what I'm doing is:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
  for line in f:
    if line.rstrip('\n') == 'ABCD':
      continue
```

But the `continue` only advances the for loop by 1 iteration. So, how can I make it to advance one more iteration to get the line I actually need?

Comment: The obvious option is using `re` for regex. Try to extract this number using  `re.match(r'\d*', your_text)` or something similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could explicitly call `next` on `f`<sup>*</sup> (which the for loop usually does for you) and advance the iterator and then call `continue`:

```
for line in f:
    if line.rstrip('\n') == 'ABCD':
        next(f)
        continue
    print(line)
```

This will now print:

```
....

unknown number of lines

....

a number I want to read

....

....
```

Thereby skipping `'ABCD'` and `'some random stuff'`.

In the general case where you are certain `ABCD` is **not** the final element, this should not cause issues. If you want to be on the safe side, though, you could wrap it in a `try - except` to catch the `StopIteration` exception.

---

<sup>*</sup> In this case, this works because `f` is it's own `iterator` i.e `iter(f) is f`. In general, this is not the case, for lists the iterator is it's own distinct object `list_iterator` so advancing it like this will not work.

Comment: Note that this only works if `f` is an iterator. That may be the case for files, but if `f` were a `list`, you would get an error doing this. (You could of course get around that by creating and iterator and assigning it to a variable before the loop and then using it as the object looped over.)

Comment: @jpmc26 That's indeed true; I'll add that in since other people bumping into this might get confused.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with this approach then do this:

```
f = open(filename,'r'):
while f.readline().rstrip('\n') != 'ABCD': # this will advanced the pointer to the ABCD line
    continue
f.next() # to skip over the unnecessary stuff
desiredNumber = f.readline()  # desired line
```

I think regex would look a lot better, but if you want something to get the work done, here it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any information at all from the skipped line, you can advance the file manually by a line before `continue`ing:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip('\n') == 'ABCD':
            next(f)     # The next iteration of the for loop will skip a line
            continue
```

If the *only* thing you need from this file is that one line, there's no need to `continue` at all. Just skip a line, grab the next line, do whatever you need to do with it, and `break` out of the `for` loop, all from within that `if` block.

Comment: It's generally better to use `next` instead of `readline` for this. I don't know what promises Python 3 makes, but on Python 2, mixing file iteration and `readline` explicitly doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Jim's use of `next()`, but another option is to just use a flag:

```
with open(filename,'r') as f:
  skip_line = False
  for line in f:
    if line.rstrip('\n') == 'ABCD':
      skip_line = True
      continue
  if skip_line == True:
    skip_line = False
  else:
    print(line)
```